# Uno-Platform: How to add a Library

Tags: uno-platform

Uno Platform...

In VS2019 (out of the box tests):

- added uno templates: all good
- create project.....: all good
- run WASM project...: all good
- run UWP project....: all good
- added a Uno Library: various issues (see list below)

Uno Library (in UWP and WASM) issues:

- complaint about a android 10 library... I remove it and compile OK
- after adding this library to the UWP project found multiple netstandard2 compilation code;

I am using the uno project template as is...  but can't even add a Uno-Library without adding any code, just what ever is generated by the wizard.

Question:

I will like to prepare a library and add it to any target... any advise?

Ed.

Comment: Without additional errors in your question, it's difficult to help you. Also, you're likely needing to install the Android 10 SDK.

Comment: I hit same issue. See sample:https://github.com/Radical-Dave/Shared.UnoLibraryIssue  
Error message given as soon as you reference the Uno Library in the other project(s): Could not find android.jar for API level 29. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 29 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar missing.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears (so far) to be a successful workaround:

Temporarily move the uap10.0.xxx target framework to be at least second in the TargetFrameworks list. (See this for more details: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/3909)